# Внутри раненная?

Tags: прилагательные

Владимир Познер: Александра, вы как-то сказали, что ваш образ — «дерзкая девчонка, внутри раненая». В самом деле раненая?

Наверное, в первом случае - раненная?

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы сказал, что оба варианта возможны. Внутри красная, белая, счастливая, несчастная, раненая... Такое же прилагательное.

Comment: _Niemand: Я бы сказал, что оба варианта возможны_. === Пожалуй, Вы правы. Свой ответ удалю.

Answer (score 1):

Формально в обоих случаях пишется "раненный", так как при наличии зависимых слов глагольная форма считается причастием (этот формальный признак действует практически всегда, но исключения бывают). Во втором предложении наречие "внутри" подразумевается.

**Из правил Лопатина:** Примечание. Как видно из примеров, **причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов**. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда зависимое слово не является признаком причастия. Напр., следует писать: у него усики явно крашеные (ср. явно искусственные, где слово явно употреблено при прилагательном); стены, раньше белёные, теперь покрыты зелёной краской (ср. стены, раньше белые).

Может ли данный вариант попасть под исключение и  писаться с одной буквой Н? Скорее всего, нет, так как зависимое слово переходит из глагольного сочетания: ранить внутри - раненная внутри.

Comment: +1 Обоснованный ответ

Comment: Думаю, что "может и должен": это не способ нанесения раны (кто-то залез с оружием внутрь и ранил), а взгляд на рану; если заглянуть в душу, посмотреть изнутри - да, оказывается она ранена, несёт в себе рану, у неё раненая душа и т.п. - вопреки соблазну подвести это под универсальное правило чудодействия зависимых слов :) . Аналогия с цветом (как прилагательным) правильно уже приводилась.

Comment: При наличии ЗАВИСИМЫХ СЛОВ выбрать количество Н по значению сложно, так как  само правило носит формальный характер, поэтому на первое место выдвигается анализ ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЙ. По Лопатину,   исключения возможны в том случае, если "зависимое слово не является признаком причастия", то есть не входит в глагольное сочетание. Сравнить: "явно крашеные (ненатуральные) волосы" не соотносится с глаг. сочетанием "явно красить волосы". Если же такая соотнесенность возможна, то мы считаем, что зависимое слово  перешло  к причастию  из глаг. сочетания, а не является собственным признаком прилагательного.

Comment: Sibylla, вы не учитываете важную вещь: здесь "раненый" в переносном смысле. Если использовать причастие, получится иной смысл: как писал Александр, "кто-то залез с оружием внутрь и ранил". Подразумевается не действие, а признак. Причастие всегда указывает на действие, а прилагательное - признак, качество. Поэтому одно н.

Comment: к тому же, почему Вы считаете, что здесь зависимое слово именно при причастии, а не при прилагательном? Ср.: внутри несчастная ( здесь внутри -  сочетается с прилагательным.

Comment: Серж, во-первых, в словаре  "ранить душу"  не выделяется даже отдельной статьей, и о переносном значении ничего не говорится. РАНИТЬ,  Нанести - наносить рану (раны). Тяжело, легко р. Р. на фронте. Р. осколком снаряда, незаслуженным упрёком. Раненный в плечо. Р. душу.  Во-вторых,  влияние зависимых слов на выбор Н/НН    вообще понимается  и объясняется с трудом, разбирать семантику каждого слова сложно (да и не нужно), поэтому и введено это формальное правило, чтобы избавить пользователя от сложного грамматического анализа.

Comment: Напишете одну букву Н - и будете всем доказывать, почему вы правы, и вряд ли докажете, что это "неправильное" зависимое слово. В третьих, надо писать ПО ЛОПАТИНУ,  то есть доказать, что при выборе Н мы имеем исключение. Но причастие - это форма глагола, поэтому причастие имеет те же зависимые слова, что и глагол: ранить внутри - раненный внутри. Поэтому "внутри" - это не собственное зависимое слово данной глагольной формы, соответственно, под исключение не подходит.

Comment: Ранить солдата - раненый солдат. здесь тоже надо писать два н?

Comment: Ранить - , раню, ранишь, сов. и несов., кого-что.
1. Нанести (наносить) кому-н. рану. его ранили на войне.
2. ***перен. Причинить (причинять) кому-н. душевную боль,скорбь***       (книжн.). Слова его ранят (наст. вр.) душу.; ***(Толковый словарь Ожегова)***

Comment: Вы пишите: "Но причастие - это форма глагола, поэтому причастие имеет те же зависимые слова, что и глагол" . Внутри вполне сочетается с прилагательным, а значит, это зависимое слово то же может быть при прилагательным.

Comment: Это по Розенталю: Разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выбор написания нн или н) иногда производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому значению. Т. е. важно и смысл учитывать, а не просто формальную грамматику.

Comment: Как  пользователи русского языка пишут слово ранен(нн)ый? Обычно очень правильно пишут: раненный (две буквы НН) - при наличии зависимых слов, раненый (одна буква Н) - при их отсутствии. Но вот в отношении "душевно ранен(нн)ый"  мнения разошлись, чаще (надо признать) пишется одна буква Н, хотя две НН также встречаются. Пишут, скорее всего, по интуиции, вряд ли кто из них знаком с исключением из лопатинского правила, учитывая. что можно встретить, к примеру, такое написание: душевно-раненые. Так что выбирайте, как вам удобнее писать: по правилу (две  буквы НН)  или по интуиции (одна  буква Н).